# How can I find a DIV with a sibling with a specific text and print it Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to fetch text from a div, but there are allot of duplicated classes. The only way to filter my search is by checking for a specific text within a sibling. Right now this is what I got:

```
accountmanager = ()
def send_keys_in_loop_dropaccountmanager(locator):
    for i in range(5):
        try:
            global accountmanager
            test = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator)).text
            print(test)
            accountmanager = test
            break
        except:
            pass
send_keys_in_loop_dropaccountmanager((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'ahoy-value')] and following-sibling::div[contains(text(),'Accountmanager')]"))
print("accountmanager:", accountmanager)
```

I get no response at all.

Google inspector code(text that I want selected in blue):```

[image]

Comment: can you share a link to the page and clarify what exactly you trying to do there and what is the difficulty?

Comment: Hi Prophet, like yesterday i sadly cant share the page, i need to print the text element(name of person) from the div with class: ahoy-value, but the name "Peter Hendriks" is dynamic, so i cant search on that element. therefor i want to search for the div class ahoy-label with the text "Accountmanager" then grab the sibbling ahoy-value and get the text element and print it. I already figured that i dont need the whole loop this time, so i deleted that already, I just cant figure out the xpath for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate the parent element with class `ahoy-label-value-pair` based on known child element text content and then find the another child of that parent, as following:

```py
"//div[@class='ahoy-label-value-pair'][contains(.,'Accountmanager')]//div[@class='ahoy-value']"
```

The selenium code for this will look as following:

```py
accountmanager = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ahoy-label-value-pair'][contains(.,'Accountmanager')]//div[@class='ahoy-value']"))).text
print("accountmanager name: ", accountmanager)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following xpath -

```
//div[text()='Peter Hendrik'][@class='ahoy-value']
```

Edit: If you want to go through the `Accountmanager` text, you can use the following xpath -

```
//div[text()='Accountmanager'][@class='ahoy-label']/following-sibling::div[@class='ahoy-value']
```

Comment: That would work, but the text element is dynamic so i cant search for "Peter Hendrik"

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, by removing the loop, checking other posts, and dubble checking, my xpath, I came up with the following:

```
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(text(), 'Accountmanager')]/following-sibling::div")))
accountmanager = element.text
print("accountmanager:", accountmanager)
```

Comment: I see you found the solution by yourself while I was writing my solution. Both should work.

Comment: Next time please share the XML/HTML as a text, not as a picture